# Error using RandomNumberGenerator does not have create function

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I trying to use **RandomNumberGenerator** instead of new Random in order to generate Cryptographic random number, but displays this error
**RandomNumberGenerator** does not contain a definition for *Create*

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
.
.
.
private int example()
{
    int number = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
    .........
    .........
    return number;
}
```

Comment: You might want to recheck the return type of `RandomNumberGenerator.Create()`

Comment: it does not work

Comment: Hi @marcus, for your reference, `RandomNumberGenerator.Create()` will return instance of `RandomNumberGenerator`, thus you will get the error because you assign it into an `int` variable which the type is not matched. [RandomNumberGenerator.Create Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.create?view=netframework-4.8#System_Security_Cryptography_RandomNumberGenerator_Create)

Comment: For .Net 5, it is supported to return `int` type with [`RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32 Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.getint32?view=net-5.0). Thus, you may evaluate that your project framework does it supported for .NET 5 or alternative find another solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you go to `System.Security.Cryptography` class, you will see that the Create() method returns `RandomNumberGenerator`, so you can't put that in the int variable.

Instead, use this syntax.

```
private static RandomNumberGenerator rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
    private static int GenerateSomeStatic(int size)
    {
        var Some = new byte[size];
        rng.GetBytes(Some);
        int a = BitConverter.ToInt32(Some);
        return a;
    }
```